# How to make EF-Core use a Guid instead of String for its ID/Primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-3

When I look at the ASP.NET 3 Identity it uses a `string` and not a `Guid` for the unique primary key.

In my `Entity Framework` `code first` Users' `ApplicationUser` class I inherit the Identity class

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

which results in when I create my Entity Framework migrations a table `aspnetusers` getting created with a key type of`nvarchar(450)` instead of `uniqueidentifier`

When I compare this to `ASP.NET Identity 2` `ENtity Framework` project it created an ID field of `uniqueidentifier` and not `nvarchar(450)`

I would imagine for database performance primary keys and foreign keys of `uniqueidentifier` would be better than `nvarchar(450)`

Is there a way to use for the unique key `Guid` instead of `string` and `uniqueidentifier` instead of `nvarchar(450)` with `ASP.NET Identity 3`?

There is a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460212/how-can-the-identity-getuserid-be-made-to-return-a-guid-instead-of-a-string) how to convert a String to a Guid but I want the database table Id to be a Guid.

I found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134589/why-did-the-new-asp-net-identity-tables-stop-using-guid-uniqueidentifier-type) as well for a previous BETA when the length was nvarchar(128). The reason given is that not all databases support Guids and it was changed for flexibility.

Is there must be an easy way to change from string to Guid without rewriting the whole `identity 3`?

`nvarchar(450)` is really overkill and gives all kinds of warnings when creating SQL Server database constraints. Database admins will definitively not like these warnings.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You need custom `ApplicationUser` inherit from `IdentityUser<TKey>` and custom Role inherit from `IdentityRole<TKey>`

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid> { }    
public class Role : IdentityRole<Guid> { }
```

Custom context class inherit from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, Role, TKey>` and use fluent api for auto generate guid keys.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, Role, Guid>
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b =>
        {
            b.Property(u => u.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()");
        });

        builder.Entity<Role>(b =>
        {
            b.Property(u => u.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()");
        });
    }
}
```

then in Startup add Identity service to container like this

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, Role>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, Guid>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddUserStore<UserStore<ApplicationUser, Role, ApplicationDbContext, Guid>> ()
        .AddRoleStore<RoleStore<Role, ApplicationDbContext, Guid>>();
```

If you have not created the database, clear the migrations folder and run ef commands

Comment: Please note, that there is a bug in EntityFramework 7 / EntiryFramework Core 1.0 up until rc1-final, which breaks migrations when using generics in foreign keys, that are not closed over the built-in types (like Guid). This is fixed in rc2-nightlies for quite some time, but it's not released yet. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3545

Comment: i've upvoted this. it also works well in .net core 2.2. it's even better example than the code provided on msdn.

Comment: this is not working with ASP.Net Core 3.1 - the AddEntityFrameworkStores doesn't have method that tales 2 generic params, the 2nd being the Type - how can we do this with ASP.Net Core 3.1?

Comment: What if I would like to change the key for the IdentityUser to Guid but keep the Role key as int? I tried to make Role : IdentityRole<int> but I got problems with setting up the context.

Answer (score 15):

I haven't messed with the migrations for this example yet (they might need some tweaks), however ASP.NET Identity v3 is far more extensible than v2 was in this regard.

The following should give you an Identity store based on Guid primary keys for Users and Roles alike:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
}

public class GuidDataContext :
    IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<Guid>, Guid>
{
}
```

and in your startup class:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<Guid>>(
            identity =>
            {
                // whatever identity options you want
                identity.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                identity.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            }).
            AddEntityFrameworkStores<GuidDataContext, Guid>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Likewise, if you didn't need to add any custom fields to the Identity User, or customize your options, you could just do the following:

```
public class GuidDataContext :
    IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser<Guid>, IdentityRole<Guid>, Guid>
{ 
}
```

and in your startup:

```
services
    .AddIdentity<IdentityUser<Guid>, IdentityRole<Guid>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<GuidDataContext, Guid>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: where does `AddEntityFrameworkStores<GuidDataContext, Guid>()` come from? I only have `AddEntityFrameworkStores<GuidDataContext>()` without option of passing second type to `AddEntityFrameworkStores`

Comment: @O.MeeKoh this response was 4 and half years ago, and depending on changes to the API since then, it may not longer be relevant. I would love to point you in the right direction but I'm unfortunately out of the loop the past couple of years. I'll try to take a look at the current API sometime soon.

Answer (score 3):

ApplicationUser inherits from [IdentityUser](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityUser.cs) base class which is defined as having a string as id. So to really use a guid/uniqueidentifier you would need to not inherit from that base class.

Note that internally it is using guid strings for ids. You should at least be able to limit the field size of the key like shown here:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b =>
        {
            // you could limit the field size to just long enough for a guid id as string
            b.Property(p => p.Id)
                .HasMaxLength(36);

            // instead, you could define the id as Guid but more work required
            //b.Property(p => p.Id)
            //   .ForSqlServerHasColumnType("uniqueidentifier")
            //   .ForSqlServerHasDefaultValueSql("newid()")
            //   .IsRequired();

        });

    }
}
```

It is possible to use Guids/uniqueidentifier for the key but that will require more work, in addition to using your own base class (or not use a base class at all) and use a custom DbContext to map the model. Borrowing and modifying the [EF code from here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityDbContext.cs) should get you going, you would have to inherit from [UserStore](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/UserStore.cs) and override the virtual methods for looking up a user by id, because the interface [IUserStore](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/IUserStore.cs) defines the FindById method signature with a string. So overriding you would need to convert the string to a guid inside the methods where you need to fetch or find by id.

I'm doing exactly that in my [cloudscribe project](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe) which has a custom multi-tenant implementation of Identity

EDIT: actually looking closer at the code the IdentityUser has a generic version where you can define the type of the key

```
public class IdentityUser<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
```

So you might be able to just define your own base class like

```
IdentityUser<Guid>
```

but I still think you would need to override the  UserStore methods that take an id string and convert the string to a guid.