# Override Identity ID type in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to change the type of ID from the string default on an identity user.
I get an exception when trying to register the Identity Service, in the configure services method.

This is what I'm trying to do in my Startup.ConfigureServices method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

        services.AddDbContext<UserContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserContext>();
      //.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddDbContext<MusicContext>(options =>
                   options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
          new IdentityOptionConfiguration(options);
        });    
     services.AddMvc();   
}
```

Here is my class which inherits IdentityUser. This is where I'm trying to override the string type. I want it to be an int or maybe even a guid. I'm not sure which yet, but I'm going with an int for now.

```
 public class User : IdentityUser<int>
 {
    public int ID { get; set; }
 }
```

And here is the role that I'm trying to use. I'm okay with the default roles that are given for the most part.

```
 public class Role : IdentityRole
 {
 }
```

Now the exception I'm getting is as follows...

> System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: GenericArguments[0],
>   'MusicianProject.Services.User', on
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`4[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey]'
>   violates the constraint of type 'TUser'.

Based off of the wording of the error, I believe it's mad that I'm trying to change the type. What am I missing here?

Comment: example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166098/how-to-make-ef-core-use-a-guid-instead-of-string-for-its-id-primary-key/37173202#37173202) using Guid for PK

Comment: @tmg: You should have initiated a close vote for it, so it gets clearly marked as duplicate and future users get pointed to it

Comment: @Tseng you are right

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to tmg for linking me to a similar problem. That post fixed my situation. Although I'm having some sort of operand clash with guid and int when I try to create a migration. I'll try to figure that out.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure out your migration issue? I suspect I may be running into the same problem.

Comment: I did. However I'm blanking on what fixed it. I think it was the  b.Property(u => u.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()"); part. Get rid of that and try running migrations. If that doesn't fix it, let me know. Sorry for the late reply.