# Error CS1061 'IdentityBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddEntityFrameworkStores'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to change the primary key in ASPNET Core 2.0 to `Guid` or `long`.

I've tried the following examples in both these links
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166098/how-to-make-ef-core-use-a-guid-instead-of-string-for-its-id-primary-key) and [Link2](http://thienn.com/change-primary-key-aspnetcore-identity-and-more/)

However, in the Startup class I get the following error

```
 Error  CS1061  'IdentityBuilder' does not contain a definition for
 'AddEntityFrameworkStores' and no extension method 'AddEntityFrameworkStores' accepting 
 a first argument of type 'IdentityBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using 
 directive or an assembly reference?)
```

[image]

I think the reason is the examples are based on the older ASPNET Core 1.0. How can I change the primary key for Identity in ASPNET Core 2.0?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @devC I had to install [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/)

Answer (score 16):

Credit on how to do this can be found in the comments in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x

Change ApplicationUser to inherit from IdentityUser<int>

Create a new class ApplicationRole that inherits from IdentityRole<int>

Change ApplicationDbContext to inherit from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>`

Change startup.cs for services.AddIdentity to use ApplicationRole

Change UrlHelperExtensions methods to take a generic <T> with T userId in the signature

Change ManageController's LinkLoginCallback's call to

```
await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(user.Id.ToString())
```

Add the following line to the ApplicationDbContext OnModelCreating method (after the base.OnModelCreating call)

```
builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.Id).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
```

If using `Guid` then replace

```
builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.Id).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
```

with

```
builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

All changes are below

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid>
{
    
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>
{
    Public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions < ApplicationDbContext > Options): Base (Options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        // For Guid Primary Key
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        // For int Primary Key
        //builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.Id).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
    }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

    services.AddMvc();
}

public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string EmailConfirmationLink<T>(this IUrlHelper urlHelper, T userId, string code, string scheme)
    {
        return urlHelper.Action(
            action: nameof(AccountController.ConfirmEmail),
            controller: "Account",
            values: new { userId, code },
            protocol: scheme);
    }

    public static string ResetPasswordCallbackLink<T>(this IUrlHelper urlHelper, T userId, string code, string scheme)
    {
        return urlHelper.Action(
            action: nameof(AccountController.ResetPassword),
            controller: "Account",
            values: new { userId, code },
            protocol: scheme);
    }
}

....
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(user.Id.ToString());
```

Comment: i make the all changes like this, but  i got the run time error can u look at this 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50579422/net-core-user-table-id-column-string-to-int-migration-and-runtime-error

Answer (score 12):

What fixed it for me was just adding '**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore**' via NuGet

If it's anything like a Similar issue I had when adding Identity to my Core 3.1 project then this may have been moved into a separate NuGet Package. ([I updated my .NET CORE project from 2.1 to 3.1, yet I have some errors in the class Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60659122/i-updated-my-net-core-project-from-2-1-to-3-1-yet-i-have-some-errors-in-the-cl))

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by changing my `ApplicationDbContext` to inherit from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, after installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore from the Nuget Package Manager
my error is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Add this nugget package '
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore' to the project and rebuild