# Guid Instead of string for primary key / ID for ASP.Net Core 3.1 Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

This no longer works with ASP.Net Core 3.1 / .Net Core 3.1

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37173202/1698480

Compile error:'IdentityBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddEntityFrameworkStores' and no accessible extension method 'AddEntityFrameworkStores' accepting a first argument of type 'IdentityBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    WebSite.Site    C:\WorkSource....\Startup.cs   32  Active

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid> { }
public class Role : IdentityRole<Guid> { }

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, Role, Guid>
{
   ...
}

public class Startup
{
    ...
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, Role>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, Guid>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddUserStore<UserStore<ApplicationUser, Role, ApplicationDbContext, Guid>>()
            .AddRoleStore<RoleStore<Role, ApplicationDbContext, Guid>>();

    }
}
```

If I just remove the Guid generic arg like this:

```
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, Guid>()
```

then I get browser error: This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:50827/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F

How can I do this?  thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error CS1061 'IdentityBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddEntityFrameworkStores'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671570/error-cs1061identitybuilder-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-addentityframe)

Comment: thank you for reply, no not really, when I create UrlHelperExtensions and add the methods it can't find AccountController.  added identity scaffold item and it still is not there.  seems this is now using razor pages?  anyway if i don't include that, I get other errors:

Comment: seems like a lot has changed with asp.net core 3.1, i will go through this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1   also perhaps use this for MVC instead of razor pages https://github.com/TanvirArjel/AspNetCoreMvcIdentity

Answer (score 2):

This first part is just like before:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid> { }
public class Role : IdentityRole<Guid> { }

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, Role, Guid>
{
   ...
}
```

And then you do the rest like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    … 
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, Role>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddUserStore<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>()
            .AddRoleStore<RoleStore<Role>>();

    }
}
```

Note that ASP.NET Core 3.1 has become quite clever in figuring everything out, such as identifying that you are using GUIDs for identity. You don’t even need to specify the `ApplicationDbContext` type, `ApplicationUser` type, and `Role` type in your `Startup`; when you mention these classes, it just looks them up via reflection and figures out the details by itself.